# C# - bunifu animation doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, visual-studio-2013

While debugging the project the animation of the panel doesn't show... It only lags but doesn't show the transition.

```
if (sidePanel.Width == 260)
{
    PanelAnimator.ShowSync(sidePanel);
    sidePanel.Width = 0;
    panelProduct.Height = 0;
    panelOrdering.Height = 0;
    panel4.AutoScroll = false;
}
else
{
    PanelAnimator.ShowSync(sidePanel);
    sidePanel.Width = 260;
    panel4.AutoScroll = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `PanelAnimator.ShowSync(sidePanel);` should be `PanelAnimator.HideSync(sidePanel);` since the **sidepanel** is already shown.

PS: sidepanel Visible property should be false before ShowSync(panel) V.V

Something like

```
 if (sidePanel.Width == 260)
{

    sidePanel.Width = 0;
    panelProduct.Height = 0;
    panelOrdering.Height = 0;
    panel4.AutoScroll = false;
    PanelAnimator.HideSync(sidePanel);
}
else
{

    sidePanel.Width = 260;
    panel4.AutoScroll = true;
    PanelAnimator.ShowSync(sidePanel);
}
```